# $anchorScrollProvider.disableAutoScrolling(): undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I’m using Angular 1.3.15. I’m trying to disable automatic scrolling when the hash changes.

According to the [documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ng/provider/$anchorScrollProvider) I need to call `disableAutoScrolling()` on the `$anchorScrollProvider`. So here’s my code:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", [
    // ... dependencies here ...
]);

app.config(['$locationProvider', '$anchorScrollProvider', function($locationProvider, $anchorScrollProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: false });
    $anchorScrollProvider.disableAutoScrolling();
}]);
```

This, however, throws an “undefined is not a function” error on the second to last line.

Any ideas why it’s happening?

Thanks.

Comment: I can't see why that wouldn't work - are you sure there's nothing else causing the error?

Comment: @TonyBarnes The error message points me exactly to that line; and if I comment it out, the error goes away.

Comment: Odd, can you get a plunker or something up?

Comment: I've re-done it. My first jsbin was a false positive.

Here's the new one: http://jsbin.com/xuroxuzopu/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Seems to work fine... you can see the relevant function being logged to console.

Comment: Thanks @AshClarke. I tried logging the function locally and it logs “undefined”. Something weird’s going on.

Comment: See what you get when you log `$anchorScrollProvider`

Comment: @BenBlack `Object {$get: function}` I’m not familiar with AngularJS enough to understand it. I’m guessing it’s some kind of a magic method?

Comment: That's what you should see, take a look at this, http://jsbin.com/gehitavowe/2/edit?html,js,console,output, you should see more inside $get. I set it to log `$anchorScrollProvider` and you can see it shows `$get`, below all the minified js it shows `disableAutoScrolling: function()`. Do you see that locally? And are you sure the code above is 100% exactly what you have in your project?

Comment: No, @BenBlack. This is what I see locally: http://i.imgur.com/GWFHHnf.png

Comment: @pankajparkar Providers don’t have dependencies.

Comment: Okay, can you post your entire module file, because something else is happening and I can't determine what it is. Unless that is your ENTIRE module file, in which case I have no idea.

Comment: I wanted to say that you must have other dependancy like `$anchorScrollProvider` in your code, please add you whole config in you question

Comment: @BenBlack That’s all there is. It’s the init file. Everything else is just controllers, directives and services. But the error happens before it loads any of those.

Comment: Let's continue here, http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75412/room-for-ben-black, so we're not spamming comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>Solution is</del> *The issue was* rather embarrassing (this is the author of the question, BTW).

While looking for a way to disable auto scrolling, some people suggested that the only way to make it actually work was to remove `$anchorScroll` from the module.

So in one of my controllers I’d added `.value($anchorScroll, angular.noop)` and forgot about it. Obviously that removed `$anchorScroll` from my module hence the errors.

Thanks everyone for help. You guided me towards the solution.